# React Help! Error - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, append, jsx

I'm building a quiz page for an app that is being built with React but I keep getting this error
"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append')"

It was working fine before I tried intergrating that quiz into react.

It probably needs to be refactored in some way but I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

The Code is

```
import React from "react";

function PlantQuiz() {
  const questionDisplay = document.querySelector("#questions");
  const answerDisplay = document.querySelector("#answer");

  const questions = [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: "Of These, Which Is Your Favorite Color?",
      answers: [
        {
          text: "Red"

        },
        {
          text: "Blue"

        },
        {
          text: "Green"
          
        },
        {
          text: "Yellow"
         
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Which Continent Do You Live On?",
      answers: [
        {
          text: "Africa"
          
        },
        {
          text: "North America"
          
        {
          text: "South America"
          
        },
        {
          text: "Asia"
          
        },
        {
          text: "Australia"
         
        },
        {
          text: "Europe"
        },
        {
          text: "Antarctica"
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Which Of These Movies Would You Choose To See?",
      answers: [
        {
          text: "The Fast and the Furious"
          
        },
        {
          text: "Harry Potter and The Sorcerer's Stone"
         
        },
        {
          text: "The Lion King"
          
        },
        {
          text: "Us"
        },
        {
          text: "Crazy Rich Asians"
        },
        {
          text: "Gone Girl"
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const answers = [
    {
      combination: ["Red", "Africa", "The Lion King"],
      text: "Cape Primrose",
      alt: "Cape Primrose",
      continent: "Africa",
    },
    {
      combination: ["Blue", "Asia", "Us"],
      text: "Jubaea Chilensis",
      alt: "Jubaea Chilensis",
      continent: "South America",
    },
    {
      combination: ["Yellow", "Europe", "Gone Girl"],
      text: "Tussock Grass",
      alt: "Tussock Grass",
      continent: "Antarctica",
    },
    {
      combination: ["Green", "South America", "The Fast and the Furious"],
      text: "Edgeworthia Chrysantha",
      alt: "Edgeworthia Chrysantha",
      continent: "Asia"
    },
    {
      combination: [
        "Green",
        "North America",
        "Harry Potter and The Sorcerer's Stone",
      ],
      text: "Spruce",
      alt: "Spruce",
      continent: "North America",
    },
    {
      combination: ["Red", "Antarctica", "Crazy Rich Asians"],
      text: "Waratah",
      alt: "Waratah"
    },
    {
      combination: [
        "Yellow",
        "Australia",
        "Harry Potter and The Sorcerer's Stone",
      ],
      text: "Bavarian Genrian",
      alt: "Bavarian Genrian"
    },
  ];



  const unansweredQuestions = [];
  const chosenAnswers = [];
  const { location } = window;

  const populateQuestions = () => {
    questions.forEach((question) => {
      const titleBlock = document.createElement("div");
      titleBlock.id = question.id;
      titleBlock.classList.add("title-block");
      const titleHeading = document.createElement("h2");
      titleHeading.textContent = question.text;
      titleBlock.append(titleHeading);
      questionDisplay.append(titleBlock);

      const answersBlock = document.createElement("div");
      answersBlock.id = question.id + "-questions";
      answersBlock.classList.add("answer-options");

      unansweredQuestions.push(question.id);

      question.answers.forEach((answer) => {
        const answerBlock = document.createElement("div");
        answerBlock.classList.add("answer-block");
        answerBlock.addEventListener("click", () =>
          handleClick(question.id, answer.text)
        );
        const answerImage = document.createElement("img");
        answerImage.setAttribute("src", answer.img);
        answerImage.setAttribute("alt", answer.alt);

        const answerTitle = document.createElement("h3");
        answerTitle.textContent = answer.text;

        answerBlock.append(answerImage, answerTitle);

        answersBlock.append(answerBlock);
      });

      questionDisplay.append(answersBlock);
    });
  };
  populateQuestions();

  const handleClick = (questionId, chosenAnswer) => {
    if (unansweredQuestions.includes(questionId)) {
      chosenAnswers.push(chosenAnswer);
      const itemToRemove = unansweredQuestions.indexOf(questionId);

      if (itemToRemove > -1) {
        unansweredQuestions.splice(itemToRemove, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log(chosenAnswer);
    console.log(unansweredQuestions);

    disableQuestionBlock(questionId, chosenAnswer);
    const lowestQuestionId = Math.min(...unansweredQuestions);
    location.href = "#" + lowestQuestionId;

    if (!unansweredQuestions.length) {
      // scroll to bottom of page
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
      showAnswer();
    }
  };

  const showAnswer = () => {
    let result;
    answers.forEach((answer) => {
      if (
        chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[0]) +
        chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[1]) +
        chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[2])
      ) {
        result = answer;
        return;
      } else if (!result) {
        result = answers[0];
      }
    });

    console.log(result);
    const answerBlock = document.createElement("div");
    answerBlock.classList.add("result-block");
    const answerTitle = document.createElement("h3");
    answerTitle.textContent = result.text;
    const answerContinent = document.createElement("h3");
    answerContinent.textContent = `Continent: ${result.continent}`;
    const answerImage = document.createElement("img");
    answerImage.setAttribute("src", result.img);
    answerImage.setAttribute("alt", result.alt);

    answerBlock.append(answerTitle, answerImage, answerContinent);

    answerDisplay.append(answerBlock);

    const allAnswerBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".answer-block");
    Array.from(allAnswerBlocks).forEach((answerBlock) =>
      answerBlock.replaceWith(answerBlock.cloneNode(true))
    );
  };

  const disableQuestionBlock = (questionId, chosenAnswer) => {
    const currentQuestionBlock = document.getElementById(
      questionId + "-questions"
    );

    Array.from(currentQuestionBlock.children).forEach((block) => {
      if (block.children.item(1).innerText !== chosenAnswer) {
        block.style.opacity = "50%";
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div onLoad="PlantQuiz()">
      <h1>What Magnificent Plant Art Thou??</h1>
      <p>Let's Find Out!</p>

      <div id="questions"></div>

      <div id="answer"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PlantQuiz;
```

Comment: The problem is that the element isn't mounted when the component first runs. But why are you manually building HTML? If you want to keep doing it that way you will need to do it inside a `useEffect` which will run *after* mount (and ideally store your element references in a `ref` not via query)

Comment: This is a serious mistake in using react. I'm recommended you to consult the react doc and gain a clear understanding of component lifecycle. eg. useRef -> document.querySelector